# How do I get the correct weights using Markowitz

Tags: python, data-science, quantitative-finance

I need some help. I´m trying to run a Markowitz Model for multiple portfolios (different weights) with the same assets. But I´d like a function that seeks for a given risk and/or returns on all possible portfolios and returns it´s weights.
My code:

```
returns_portfolio = []
risks_portfolio = []

for x in range(1000):
    weights = np.random.random(number_of_assets)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    returns_portfolio.append(np.sum(weights * log_returns.mean()) * 250)
    risks_portfolio.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(log_returns.cov() * 250, weights))))
    
returns_portfolio = np.array(returns_portfolio)
risks_portfolio = np.array(risks_portfolio)
returns_portfolio, risks_portfolio

portfolios = pd.DataFrame({'Returns' : returns_portfolio, 'Risks' : risks_portfolio})
portfolios.plot(x = 'Risks', y = 'Returns', kind = 'scatter')
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is your example input and expected output?

Comment: I got the assets adjusted price via yahoo API, then, I did log returns and variances.